# Linear Equation Problem Solving.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A 120-page book has p lines to a page. If the number of lines were reduced to by three on each page, the number of pages would need to be increased by 20 to give the same amount of writing space. How many lines were there on each page originally?

Comment: What have you tried?  How many total lines are there?  Write an equation that says both versions of the book have the same number of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$120p=(120+20)(p-3)$$

I'll leave you to continue from here.